# Subtracting dates in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

I have timestamps stored in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (for example `2010-06-21 20:12:56`). What would the best way to check how old the timestamp is? For the moment I am mainly interested in the number of days old.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the string to a UNIX timestamp, which is in seconds. `time()` will give you the current UNIX timestamp. Subtract them to get how old the date is in seconds, and divide by `60*60*24` to get it in days

It's also doable using [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), although I find the date functions easier than using the classes

Comment: Don't do this, you will fail miserably once DST comes into play:

``
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
    $d1 = strtotime("2013-10-27T00:00:00");
    $d2 = strtotime("2013-10-28 00:00:00");
    var_dump(($d2-$d1)/(60*60*24));
``

output: double(1.0416666666667)

Answer (score 11):

```
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$expireDay = strtotime($row['ExpireDate']);
$timeToEnd = $expireDay - $today;
```