# DateTime diff not working correctly in Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, diff

All,
I have the following PHP code to determine how many years apart two dates are on my Wordpress page:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("2003-03-24");
$current_date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$interval = $date1->diff($current_date);
echo $interval->y;
?>
```

I installed the Exec-PHP plugin for Wordpress to display this properly. However when I try and display my page I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in
>   /home/person/test.website.com/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42)
>   : eval()'d code on line 7

How can I get this to work properly? Thanks!

Comment: what version of php is installed ?

Comment: Is this only counting whole years? Should be pretty simple to write an alternative

Comment: @OptimusCrime It is only counting whole years. Do you have an alternative way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @user1048676 : Posted as answer. Please accept if satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this question a while back: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

With some small adjustments it looks like this:

```
function convert_number($number) { 
    $Gn = floor($number / 1000000);  /* Millions (giga) */ 
    $number -= $Gn * 1000000; 
    $kn = floor($number / 1000);     /* Thousands (kilo) */ 
    $number -= $kn * 1000; 
    $Hn = floor($number / 100);      /* Hundreds (hecto) */ 
    $number -= $Hn * 100; 
    $Dn = floor($number / 10);       /* Tens (deca) */ 
    $n = $number % 10;               /* Ones */ 

    $res = ""; 

    if ($Gn)
        $res .= convert_number($Gn) . " Million"; 
    if ($kn)    { 
        $res .= (empty($res) ? "" : " ") . 
        convert_number($kn) . " Thousand"; 
    } 

    if ($Hn) { 
        $res .= (empty($res) ? "" : " ") . 
        convert_number($Hn) . " Hundred"; 
    } 

    $ones = array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six","Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen","Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eightteen","Nineteen"); 
    $tens = array("", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty","Seventy", "Eigthy", "Ninety"); 

    if ($Dn || $n)  { 
        if (!empty($res))
            $res .= " and "; 

        if ($Dn < 2) 
        $res .= $ones[$Dn * 10 + $n]; 
        else { 
            $res .= $tens[$Dn]; 

            if ($n) 

            $res .= "-" . $ones[$n]; 
        } 
    } 

    if (empty($res)) 
        $res = "zero"; 

    return $res; 
} 

function yearsFromNow ($date) {
    return convert_number(floor(abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) / (365*60*60*24)));
}

echo yearsFromNow("2007-03-24");
echo yearsFromNow("2009-06-26");
```

Output:

```
4
2
```

Number to letters function modified from this site: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Numbers-to-Words.html

Comment: thank you very much that works good. The answer I got was 8. Is there anyway to make this read eight or four etc depending on what is returned?

Comment: What do you mean by "read eight or four"? With text instead of numbers?

Comment: I'm not really sure I see the point of this code - what's its advantage over something like `ceil ((time() - strtotime("2007-03-24")) / (60* 60 * 24 *365))`?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), `DateTime::Diff` (and all the `DateInterval` functions) is available in PHP >= 5.3.0 only.

You would need to install that version, or find a workaround that uses another set of functions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090067/subtracting-dates-in-php) is an example for how to do this using the old timestamp-based date functions.